# Nginx reverse proxy does not change the host

Tags: angular, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

When I use Nginx reverse proxy with my Angular app the host does not change at all. It tries to call the path but with the same url (localhost).

In the folder /etc/nginx/servers I have myAppProxy.conf with the configuration you can see bellow. Obviously, in the nginx.conf I include that path (include servers/*;).

From angular I call that path /ag-rcc-cardcontrols/controls, so that the nginx proxy should redirect to https://whatever.com/ag-rcc-cardcontrols/controls. However, I get an error response where I can see that the URl is http://localhost/ag-rcc-cardcontrols/controls.

So, I think the reverse proxy is not working.

### myAppProxy.conf

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;

  root /Users/e1205577/Documents/Workspace/card-controls-rcc-screen/dist/card-controls-rcc-screen;
index index.html index.htm;

  location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  location /ag-rcc-cardcontrols/ {
     # proxy_bind 127.0.0.1;
     proxy_pass https://whatever.com;
     proxy_pass_request_headers on;
     proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_redirect off;
     proxy_buffering off;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header Strict-Transport-Security "'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains' always";
     proxy_set_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
     proxy_set_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
     proxy_set_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
     proxy_set_header Referrer-Policy "'strict-origin-when-cross-origin' always";
     proxy_set_header Cache-Control "'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate' always";
     proxy_set_header Pragma "no-cache";
  }
}
```

### Angular code

```
handlePostRequest(url: string) {
  url = '/ag-rcc-cardcontrols/controls';

  const headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Client-id': 'client id',
    'Application-Id': 'app id',
  });

  return this.httpClient.post<Object>(url, '{"ignoreRecurring": true}', {'headers': headers}).subscribe(
    response => {
      console.log(response);
    },
    (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      console.log(error);
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: The statement `proxy_set_header Host $host;` overrides the Host header for `whatever.com` and changes it to the name used to access the proxy. Perhaps you need to remove it.

Comment: Than you so much @RichardSmith, this is working as I expect. I reviewed everything a lot of times, read a lot of information, but I hadn't realised about that header.